# What are the different types of algorithms for Matrix-Matrix multiplication/ Matrix-Vector multiplication

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

What are the different types of algorithms for matrix-matrix multiplication and matrix-vector mutliplication.

Cannon's algorithm is one such algorithm for matrix-matrix multiplication. Is there any other algorithms..

Which algorithm do you think is better???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also Fox's algorithm like Cannon's.